# Why doesn't the payment form allow '+' symbols in email address?

Tags: bug, status-completed

It's a perfectly valid address symbol. Gmail supports it ... what more evidence do you need?

http://www.jacobsen.no/anders/blog/archives/2002/08/24/email_addresses_with_a_are_valid.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, this was a (very) bad client side regex. fix deployed, you may need to CTRL+F5 on the billing page to get the new js, as we cache the content folder for about an hour.